# Calculate a*a mod n without overflow

Tags: c++, biginteger, modulo

I need to calculate `a*a` mod `n` but `a` is fairly large, resulting in overflow when I square it. Doing `((a % n)*(a % n)) % n` doesn't work because (n-1)<sup>2</sup> can overflow. This is in C++ and I'm using `int64_t`

## Edit:

Example value: a = 821037907258 and n = 800000000000, which overflows if you square it.

I am using DevCPP and I've already tried getting big-integer libraries working to no avail.

## Edit 2:

No, there's no pattern to these numbers.

Comment: Are you able to use a big-integer library?

Comment: I tried installing BigInteger, GMP, etc, but I use Windows and those libraries seem to require a billion steps that all fail for me at various points as I crawl back the list of needed dependencies.

Comment: Any number over 32bits (~4billion unsigned, ~2billion signed) squared will overflow. You can detect this condition beforehand and handle it yourself using some relatively simple 'big integer' routines.

Comment: Yes, but I think the question is whether there is a mathematical simplification that can be applied.

Comment: @Mat Simplification? Hmph, no. But the multiplication can be handled with shifts and adds, which isn't too hard to implement.

Comment: Can you use `double` and cast that after calculation to `int64`?

Comment: You'll probably need to look at an arbitrary precision math library as found in some of the various crypto packages (e.g. OpenSSL, libgcrypt). Big integers are used a lot in crypto.

Comment: If you are use `g++`, you could use `__uint128_t` and `__int128_t` extensions.

Comment: @juergend Double is 64-bits, which is what, 13 bits for the mantissa? That leaves 2 bits for signs (one for integer part, one for mantissa) and you get like, 51 bits of integer precision. That won't help the overflow much, in fact, it will overflow sooner - assuming the OP wants accuracy

Comment: @OrgnlDave: Actually the integer precision of `double` is 53 bit.

Comment: @KennyTM N is fixed, and it fits within an int64 fine. No problems there.

Comment: @Mat not sure how you're getting that the remainder is a^2-n. In a smaller case, 4^2 mod 3 = 1. But 4^2-3 = 13.

Comment: Any bigint library should work fine with this, or you had used it the wrong way. But what's the reason for avoiding `__int128_t` when it's available?

Answer (score 15):

If you can't use a big-integer library, and you don't have a native `uint128_t` (or similar), you'll need to do this manually.

One option is to express `a` as the sum of two 32-bit quantities, i.e. *a* = 2<sup>32</sup>*b* + *c*, where *b* contains the 32 msbs, and *c* contains the 32 lsbs.  Squaring is then a set of four cross-multiplications; each result is guaranteed to fit into a 64-bit type.  You then do the modulo operation as you recombine the individual terms (carefully taking into account the shifts needed to realign everything).

Comment: @OrgnlDave: Nope, each term of the cross-multiplication fits into 64 bits.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner and have no idea what this means

Comment: @WhatsInAName: No idea about which part?  Are you comfortable with the fact that a 64-bit integer can be expressed as the combination of two 32-bit integers?  And that (a+b) squared can be expressed as the sum of four multiplications?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Maybe show a sample implementation with 4- or 8-bit integers so that it's short and concise but clear?

Comment: @OrgnlDave: This is the same thing, really.  Producing that 128-bit integer requires 4 individual multiplications.

Comment: @OilCharlesworth Splitting some value into a_hi and a_lo (how do I split?) and how to do the necessary multiplications and recombinations/shifts... all that stuff is beyond my scope.

Comment: @WhatsInAName Basically, Oli is telling you to implement long multiplication and long division the same way you would do it grade-school.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm pretty sure they don't teach bitshifting and modular arithmetic in gradeschool. Please keep the snarkiness to a minimum. That is clearly not what I am asking about.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: Oli means rewriting *a* into the form *a* = 2³² *b* + *c* where 0 ≤ *b*, *c* < 2³². *b* is `a_hi` and *c* is `a_lo`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yep.  I've modified my answer, because that's a lot clearer.

Comment: @WhatsInAName I'm not trying to be snarky - I apologize if you took it that way. In grade-school arithmetic, you "shift" the digits. In computers, you "shift" the bits. It's all the same except in a different base.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to just figure out a different way to handle this entire issue in the first place. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I'll mark this as the answer anyway because I'm sure it's right, I just have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `mod(2^64, n)*b*b` (or each subterm as we calculate the end result) won't overflow? Or should we recursively apply the multiplication function described above?

Comment: @vhallac: Yes, it's possible that `mod(term,n)*mod(1<<N,n)` can overflow.  So some further decomposition is necessary.

Comment: What is msbs and lsbs?  Can you use his number in an example?  Your answer doesn't seem to apply to the question...  Please expand on it or provide a sample...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=msb+lsb. It does apply to the question; the crux is "decompose your input into chunks that fit within the types you have available".

Comment: Ah, never seen that before: https://www.google.com/search?q=msbs - Can you expand on `You then do the modulo operation as you recombine the individual terms (carefully taking into account the shifts needed to realign everything).` and give a sample?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: I haven't got the patience to work a full example ;)  However, the result of the cross-multiplication gives us something of the form `2^64 * a + 2^32 * (b + c) + d`.  Each of these remaining operations can be done in modulo arithmetic without overflowing.

Answer (score 4):

I know you no longer need this, and there is an alternative solution, but I want to add an alternative method to implement it. It provides two different techniques: the [double and add algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add), and the method to handle `mod(a + b, n)` with overflow detection.

Double and add algorithm is usually used in fields where multiplication is not possible or too costly to calculate directly (such as elliptic curves), but we could adopt it to handle it in our situation to handle overflows instead.

The following code is probably slower than the accepted solution (even when you optimize  it), but if speed is not critical, you may prefer it for clarity.

```
unsigned addmod(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned n)
{
    // Precondition: x<n, y<n
    // If it will overflow, use alternative calculation
    if (x + y <= x) x = x - (n - y);
    else x = (x + y) % n;
    return x;
}

unsigned sqrmod(unsigned a, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned b;
    unsigned sum = 0;

    // Make sure original number is less than n
    a = a % n;

    // Use double and add algorithm to calculate a*a mod n
    for (b = a; b != 0; b >>= 1) {
        if (b & 1) {
            sum = addmod(sum, a, n);
        }
        a = addmod(a, a, n);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `x = x - (n - y)` - are you sure that does anything useful?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It calculates `(x+y)%n` without overflowing. The non-overflow is simple to prove. both x and y are less than `n` (and hence maximum word size), and we are only subtracting numbers, so they only go downwards, which means they can never overflow. To prove `x - (n - y)` is correct is a little trickier. First, since it overflows, `x+y` is clearly greater than `n`. Also, since both `x` and `y` are less than  `n`, `x+y` is less than `2*n`, so the modulus is equal to `(x+y)-n`. If you write `x+y` as `x-(-y)` and rearrange terms, you get the formula I used.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think you can use the alternative formula `(x+y)+2^W-n` instead of `x-(n-y)`, but I didn't try it. This would have the advantage of letting us calculate `x+y` only once in `addmul`.

Comment: `addmod()` needs a comment saying a precondition is that `x < n` and `y < n`.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Yes. It is not obvious. I am editing the answer to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a double-and-add implementation of a multiplication `a * b % m`, without overflows, whatever the size of a, b and m.

(Note that the `res -= m` and `temp_b -= m` lines rely on 64-bit unsigned integer overflow in order to give the expected results. This should be fine since unsigned integer overflow is well-defined in C and C++. For this reason it's [important to use *unsigned* integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/60075).)

```
uint64_t mulmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t m) {
    uint64_t res = 0;
    uint64_t temp_b;

    /* Only needed if b may be >= m */
    if (b >= m) {
        if (m > UINT64_MAX / 2u)
            b -= m;
        else
            b %= m;
    }

    while (a != 0) {
        if (a & 1) {
            /* Add b to res, modulo m, without overflow */
            if (b >= m - res) /* Equiv to if (res + b >= m), without overflow */
                res -= m;
            res += b;
        }
        a >>= 1;

        /* Double b, modulo m */
        temp_b = b;
        if (b >= m - b)       /* Equiv to if (2 * b >= m), without overflow */
            temp_b -= m;
        b += temp_b;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is [my modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680280/60075) of [another answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171020/60075).

Answer (score -3):

You can implement the multiplication yourself, adding *n* each run, and mod'ing the result right away.

Comment: You realize he's talking about numbers over 4 billion, right? That's what it takes to overflow a 64-bit int...

Comment: It would take way too long for me to iterate through the a-value to do this

Comment: @OrgnlDave: that would be enough to overflow a 32-bit int. For a 64-bit int, you need something about 4 billion times that size. (Or do you mean the two inputs are over 4 billion, so multiplying them overflows a 64-bit int?)

Answer (score -5):

I really think  that `((a % n)*(a % n)) % n` should work for positive integers.  Why do you think it doesn't work?  Do you have a counter-example?  If n could be negative, then the `%` operator is undefined.

Comment: a is smaller than n. a^2 is larger than n. However, a^2 overflows.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: If `(n-1)` squared can overflow, you should have said that in the question, because the question doesn't say that.  Your question merely says that `a` squared overflows.  This answer depends on `n` squared not overflowing.

Comment: I didn't know it mattered because I'm not squaring n. But yes, n-1 squared would overflow, too.

Comment: If `n` is very large, then `a%n` can be very large.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: if `(n-1)` squared didn't overflow, then this answer would work just fine.  Please put that information in the question, so that future answerers know.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think that's necessary.  The fact that the OP is asking the question at all implies that `n-1` squared can overflow.  This answer is based on an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: Well I mean of course the answer would work if that didn't overflow (because a^2 would be smaller than that) and I've already stated that a%n does nothing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: He said that the process "didn't work", (which I admit, is a good sign that n-1 squared can overflow), but I think the question would be improved if he used better wording that "didn't work".  There's many questions here that say "didn't work" when they mean "I copy-pasted this and got a compiler error and gave up".